# nuxt Mounted hook doesnt select element after route changes

Tags: nuxt.js

I need to get the first element of something in nuxt mounted hook
and it works on first time
[image]

but when the routes changed to '/categories'
[image]

and return to '/'
the mounted hook doesnt select an element and return null

[image]

Comment: Notice that noone knows your project so we need to see your implementation first

Comment: Posting screenshots will not be relevant at all. And is also not recommended on SO at all tbh. Please share some **relevant** code and what you've tried so far please.